# XStream API response to Java with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xstream

I generated a Java Swagger client that uses Jackson for XML/JSON parsing.

API send the results of calls via XML parsed with XStream.

It's possible to fully deserialize this XStream XML content with Jackson?

Some objects, like java.util.Calendar are serialized in a non-standart way by XStream. Look at code:

```
public class GregorianCalendarConverter implements Converter {

    public  boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type.equals(GregorianCalendar.class);
    }

    public  void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = (GregorianCalendar) source;
        ExtendedHierarchicalStreamWriterHelper.startNode(writer, "time", long.class);
        long timeInMillis = calendar.getTime().getTime(); // calendar.getTimeInMillis() not available under JDK 1.3
        writer.setValue(String.valueOf(timeInMillis));
        writer.endNode();
        ExtendedHierarchicalStreamWriterHelper.startNode(writer, "timezone", String.class);
        writer.setValue(calendar.getTimeZone().getID());
        writer.endNode();
    }

    public  Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        reader.moveDown();
        long timeInMillis = Long.parseLong(reader.getValue());
        reader.moveUp();
        final String timeZone;
        if (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            timeZone = reader.getValue();
            reader.moveUp();
        } else { // backward compatibility to XStream 1.1.2 and below
            timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
        }

        GregorianCalendar result = new GregorianCalendar();
        result.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        result.setTime(new Date(timeInMillis)); // calendar.setTimeInMillis() not available under JDK 1.3

        return result;
    }
```

Can I use the XStream Converters in Jackson like a conversion module?

What is the best approach in this case? Thanks!